# How to make an element's CSS NOT inherit from others?

Tags: javascript, css

[image]
I want the element to use only css that are in the **"A"** section and ignore the **"B"** section.

Is it possible?If javascript can do this, How?

Thanks you.

Comment: `!important` is what you are looking for

Comment: Give the B section css with a class. e.g.  input.common, textarea.common {
}

Comment: With `!important` you'll need to override ALL the css rules. 
What you might find more useful, will be to attach a class to the element `A` and define its style in there using a css selector with higher specificity.

Comment: Redefine classes in b with the same name in a or use !important

Comment: This is a Firefox extension.So When it run on any web page its css change according to that web page.

Comment: You have to manually override all relevant properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not do that with the example you've provided. The C in CSS stands for Cascading, the styling rules *cascade* down the DOM tree.

You have to reset the styling of the element to what you want with a more specific selector, e.g. `#Examplewrapper input{}`. By using a more specific selector, it'll overwrite/suplement the previous styling, without the need for `!important`.

Alternatively, you can set the most upper selector more specific, e.g. `#content input{}`. This way, when you place a form in the `#footer`, it will not have the styling, as `#content` doesn't have a `#footer` in it (it cant cascade).

---

I do recommend to define a general `input` as you have. This way, all forms have the same font, size and styling throughout your website. If you want another color border, you only have to change that one settings. This is the way many (profesional) sites work, because it is the most efficient.

Answer (score 0):

This is how the inheritance works. You can only overwrite styles if others are set globally (i.e. for all `input` elements).

You can always limit the global styles of `input` with some classname, like `input.myStyle` so the *raw* `input` will have no styles set.

Comment: Indeed, this is `CSS` which means `CASCADE Style Sheet`.